# Append on all divs with same class

Tags: javascript, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to change the lay-out for WooCommerce, but since I can't get that working I decided to change it to my wishes by using Javascript to create a div and append it to the existing div. I do have some lines that go through every div with a certain class, but that only works when I let them change the innerHTML. But when I use appendChild, it only appends to the last div. Anyone have an idea what could be it? This is the code I use. The class "product-type-simple" is the div that already exists.

```
var product_item_wrapper = document.createElement("div");
  product_item_wrapper.style.width = "100px";
  product_item_wrapper.style.height = "100px";
  product_item_wrapper.style.background = "red";
  product_item_wrapper.style.color = "white";
  product_item_wrapper.innerHTML = "Hello";
  product_item_wrapper.className = "product";

var divjes = document.getElementsByClassName("product-type-simple");
  for(var i = 0; i < divjes.length; i++){
    divjes[i].appendChild(product_item_wrapper);
}
```

Comment: What were you trying to do? because changing the layout via javascript doesn't seem like the ideal approach.

Comment: @helgatheviking I can't find a way to change the layout by WooCommerce. So I thought this is the only way. Far from ideal, but it's something.

Comment: Change the layout of which page? Change to the layout from what to what? I'd advise making a question about *that* with as much detail about what you are attempting and what you've tried. I'm 95% certain we can find a better approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating one element. Then you append it as a child of multiple elements. Each time you do, you remove it from where it was before and place it in the new element.

If you want multiple elements, then you need to create multiple elements.

Move the first 7 lines of your code so they are **inside** the loop.

Answer (score 0):

One element can only be appended to a single div. Consider making a function which returns a new element to be appended:

```
function createWrapper()
{
    var product_item_wrapper = document.createElement("div");
    product_item_wrapper.style.width = "100px";
    product_item_wrapper.style.height = "100px";
    product_item_wrapper.style.background = "red";
    product_item_wrapper.style.color = "white";
    product_item_wrapper.innerHTML = "Hello";
    product_item_wrapper.className = "product";
    return product_item_wrapper;
}

var divjes = {};
divjes = document.getElementsByClassName("product-type-simple");
for (var i = 0; i < divjes.length; i++)
{
    divjes[i].appendChild(createWrapper());
}
```